# find the number of maximal three-square-free subsets of $S$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, divisibility

> Let $S = \{1,\cdots, 15\}$. Call a subset $A$ of $S$ three-square-free if there are no three distinct elements of $A$ so that their product is a perfect square. Find the number of three-square-free subsets of $S$ with the maximum cardinality, and determine what this cardinality is. As an example, $\{1,2,3\}$ is a three-square-free subset of $S$ as no three distinct elements have a product that's a square.

I know the maximum cardinality of a three-square-free subset of $S$ is $10$. Indeed, at least one element cannot be chosen from each of the following three disjoint sets: $\{1,4,9\}, \{2,6,12\}, \{3,5,15\}, \{7,8,14\},$ so the maximum cardinality is at most $11.$ Suppose for a contradiction that a three-square-free set $A$ has size $11.$ Then $10 \in A,$ and $A$ must exclude at least one element from each of the following disjoint sets: $\{1,4,9\}, \{2,5\}, \{6,15\}, \{7,8,14\}.$ Since $A$ has size $11,$ it must include $\{3,12\}$ as a subset, so it must exclude one element from each of the sets $\{1\}, \{4\}, \{9\}, \{2,5\}, \{6,15\}, \{7,8,14\}$, meaning it has size at most $10$, a contradiction.

Finally, note that $A = \{1,3,4,5,6,7,10,11,13,14\}$ works.

Comment: Source of this problem, please?

Comment: @GerryMyerson The more pressing concern is: what is the question here?

Comment: @Parcly, I think I understand the question. Take instead $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. Subset $A$ can't contain all of $2$, $3$, and $6$, since $2\times3\times6=36=6^2$. But if $A$ is missing only one of those three numbers, then there's no product of three that's a square. So the maximum cardinality is $5$, and the number of sets of five is three.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel what about the question is unclear?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I came up with this question by myself actually. Though it was based on a math contest problem.

Comment: It is a bit confusing, but I believe you've posed the problem goal in the title, without repeating it clearly in the body of the Question.  Knowing the size of maximum "three-square-free" subsets is $10$, you then want to know how many of them there are.  Also the title says "maximal" while the word "maximum" is used in the body, and the notions are not interchangeable generally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A$ be a maximum size three-square-free subset.

Case 1: For this case, suppose $10\not\in A$. We have that $A$ excludes exactly one element from each of the sets $\{1,4,9\}, \{2,6,12\}, \{3,5,15\}, \{7,8,14\}.$

Case 1a: suppose both $7$ and $14$ are included. Then both $2$ and $8$ must be excluded. We cannot have both $3$ and $12$ in the set A, as otherwise $1,4,9$ must be excluded (so at least $6$ elements are excluded. We also cannot exclude both $3$ and $12$ as otherwise we'd have to exclude at least six elements ($2,8,3,12,10$ and one of $1,4,9$). Suppose we include $3$ and exclude $12$. We must exclude one of $5,15$, and each of $2,8,10, 12,$ as well as one of $1,4,9$. But that means at least 6 elements are excluded, a contradiction. So we must include $12$ and exclude $3$. But then again one of $5,15$ must be excluded, leading to a similar contradiction to the case where we include $3$ and exclude $12$. So we cannot include both $7$ and $14$ if we exclude $10$.

Case 1b: Suppose now that we exclude $10$ and include $7$ but not $14$. Since $14\in \{7,8,14\}$, we must include $8$. Suppose we include both $3$ and $12$. Then we exclude $1,4,9,10, 14,$ and one of $\{5,15\}$, a contradiction. If we exclude both $3,12$, we must include $5,15,6,2, 8$. So we exclude $1,4,9,3,12,14$, a contradiction. So again we must include exactly one of $3$ or $12$. Suppose we include $3$. We excluded $12 \in \{2,6,12\}$, so we must include both $2$ and $6$. But then $3\cdot 2 \cdot 6$ is a perfect square, a contradiction. Hence we must exclude $3$ and include $12$. $3\in \{3,5,15\}$, so we must include $5,15$. If we exclude $2,$ we must include $6$. But then $6\cdot 8 \cdot 12 $ is a perfect square. Suppose we exclude $6$. We must include $2$. But since $2\cdot 8$ is a perfect square, we must exclude an element from each of the sets $\{1\}, \{4\},\{9\}.$ We already excluded $10,14, 12, 6,$ so we can only have at most $8$ elements.

Case 1c: Suppose we include $14$ and not $7$. $7\in \{7,8,14\}$ so we must include $8$. We cannot include $2$ because then we must exclude $1,4,9$, and we exclude $10, 7,$ and one of $\{3,5,15\}.$ So we must include both $6$ and $12$. But then $6\cdot 8 \cdot 12$ is a perfect square.

In conclusion, it is impossible for $A$ to have $10$ as an element.

Case 2: For this case, suppose $10\in A.$  From the proof in the question, we know that if A includes 10, it must include at most one of $3,12$. In fact it must include exactly one of $3,12$, since otherwise it would exclude 4 additional elements, one from each of the sets $\{1,4,9\}, \{2,5\}, \{6,15\}, \{7,8,14\}$.

Case 2aa: Suppose we include $3$ and exclude $12$. If we include both $7$ and $14$, we must exclude both $8$ and $2$. So we must include $5$. Then we cannot include $15$ as $3\cdot 5\cdot 15 $ is a square, so we must include $6$. Thus we have $3$ possibilities; exclude exactly one of $1,4,9$ from the remaining elements. One can verify that the resulting sets do work. They are $\{1,3,4,5,6,7,10,11,13,14\}, \{1,3,5,6,7,9,10,11,13,14\}, \{3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,13,14\}.$

Case 2ab: Suppose we include $7$ but not $14$. We must include $8$. We cannot include $6$ as $8\cdot 6\cdot 3$ is a square. So we must include $15$. We must exclude $5$, but then we must include $2$. $2\cdot 8$ is a square, so we must exclude $1,4,9$. $5,6,14$ are also excluded, giving a contradiction.

Case 2ac: Suppose we include $14$ but not $7$. We must include $8$, and we get a similar contradiction to case 2ab.

Case 2b: Suppose we include $12$ and exclude $3$. By similar reasoning to case 2aa, we get the possibilities $\{1,4,5,6,7,10,11,12,13,14\}, \{1,5,6,7,9,10,11,12, 13,14\}, \{4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12, 13,14\}.$ And by similar reasoning to cases 2ab and 2ac, we get no possibilities if exactly one of $7$ and $14$ is included.

**In conclusion,** there are exactly 6 maximal three-square-free subsets of $S$ with respect to inclusion, which are $\{1,3,4,5,6,7,10,11,13,14\}, \{1,3,5,6,7,9,10,11,13,14\}, \{3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,13,14\},\{1,4,5,6,7,10,11,12,13,14\}, \{1,5,6,7,9,10,11,12, 13,14\}, \{4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12, 13,14\}.$

For instance, one can verify that the set $\{4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12, 13,14\}$ indeed is three-square free as follows: if $14$ is in a product that's a perfect square, $7$ must be in it too, since it's the only other number with $7$ occurring to an odd power. Then $2$ or $8$ must be in the product, a contradiction. $13,11$ cannot be in such a product. $5$ can't be in such a product as $10$ would also have to be in it. Then $2$ or $8$ would be the third number, a contradiction. $6$ can't be in a product as $12$ would have to be in it, but then $2$ and $8$ would also have to be the third element. So the only element that can be part of a product is $4$ and thus the set is three-square-free.